# trying to locate where bash fires some message

Tags: ruby, macos, bash, rvm

Each time I open my shell, I get this message `-bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory`. Knowing I uninstalled `rvm` and deleted all `rvm` extra-files i know about. From where is this message targetted ?

Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to look at different startup files.  I'll start with `/etc/profile`.  You can also check in your personal startup files.  It may also be easier to look for this using `grep`.  For example, in your home directory, issue the following command:

```
grep -l rvm.sh .??*
```

to see which file has a reference to `rvm.sh`.